# Passing variable names to model in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating an app for simple linear regression using shiny. I want to pass variable names to the model automatically. I tried variable inputs from users. code in server.R is

```
lm(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",input$independent), data=data1())
```

and

```
lm(paste0(input$dependent) ~ paste0(input$independent), data=data1())
```

And also tried below syntax;

```
lm(names(data1()[2]) ~ names(data1()[1]) , data=data1())
```

these are all not working...
How can I pass variable names to the model?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: What type of object is `input` (e.g. a `data.frame`)? Now you tell `lm()` to search for the data in `data1`, while if I understand it correctly the dependent and independent variables are in the object `input`. If all the needed variables are indeed stored `input`, you could just do `lm(dependent ~ independent, data=input)`. But maybe you might have to look into `update.formula`.

Comment: I've a data set named "data1". It has 2 columns by header "var1" and "var2". I don't want to give variable names directly to the model like 'lm(var1~var2, data=data1)'. whatever the data if I select, it should  automatically takes the variable names into the model.

Comment: How are they not working? What are the errors or unexpected results?

Comment: Yes the below code is working;
`lm(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",input$independent), data=data1())`
But in the regression summary it's not showing proper formula. It showing the same what we entered in the code.

`Call:
lm(formula = paste(input$dependent, " ~ ", input$independent), 
    data = data1())

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)  Age_in_Months  
       64.928          0.635 `

Comment: An also It's showing below error;


`Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input 
1:   ~   
  ^
Warning in model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :  
  the response appeared on the right-hand side and was dropped`

Comment: Have you tried the get function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example isn't full enough for me to understand what errors you are running into, but I think this should do the trick:

```
    lm(as.formula(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",paste(input$independent,collapse="+"))),data=dat)
```

A junky test shows that this is able to create dynamic models (although needs a bit of tweaking in other areas):

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test Shiny App"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("dependent", "Dependent Variable:", c("x","y","z")),
    uiOutput("independent")
  ),

  mainPanel(tableOutput("regTab"))
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100),z=rnorm(100))

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$independent <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("independent", "Independent Variables:",names(dat)[!names(dat) %in% input$dependent],names(dat)[!names(dat) %in% input$dependent])
  })

  runRegression <- reactive({
    lm(as.formula(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",paste(input$independent,collapse="+"))),data=dat)
  })

  output$regTab <- renderTable({
    if(!is.null(input$independent)){
      summary(runRegression())$coefficients
    } else {
      print(data.frame(Warning="Please select Model Parameters."))
    }
  })

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to pass a formula object to the `lm` call. 
I find this easier than just using `paste0`. The question is more about `formula` than shiny, there are other ways to do this.

```
predictors = paste(input$independent,collapse="+")
fml = as.formula(sprintf('%s ~ %s', input$dependent, predictors))
fit = lm(fml, data=dat)
```