# No Plot Outout From 'ggplot2' In Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

First, a disclaimer: I am enrolled in the Coursera "Developing Data Products" course.  I was in the course last month, but work obligations took up a lot of my time and I was unable to complete the course by the deadline.  I continued to work on the course project and re-enrolled for the January course offering, which just started.

I have watched the videos on coursera and the tutorial series on the Shiny specific site through RStudio.com.  I have everything working except for the plot output from the ggplot.  The problem is there is no output.  There are no error messages, either.  I can't figure it out, so I'm hoping someone here can look at my code and point me in the right direction.

My R code is below.

Thank you!  (In advance.)

Rich

ui.R:

```
## Coursera Data Science Specialization
#  Class: Delivering Data Products
#
#  Author: Richard Ian Carpenter
#  Date Created: 14 Dec 2015
#  Data Updated: 06 Jan 2016
#
## NOTES: 
#
## I am repeating this course, unrolled from Dec 2015 course due to work obligations.
#
## Beyond the notes and videos for the class and the Shiny website, I used the 
#  following:
#
## This Stack Overflow question from 2013 helped with correcting my R code:
#  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762962/passing-variable-names-to-model-in-shiny-app
#  
## This shiny example to get the regression output to be in the same format
#  that R uses, instead of a table: https://rich.shinyapps.io/regression/
#

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
data("mtcars")

mtcars <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(
      sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("dependent", "Dependent Variable:", c(names(mtcars))),
            uiOutput("independent"),
            checkboxInput("factor", "Create factor variables (am, cyl, etc.)?")
      ),

      mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                  tabPanel("Regression Plot",
                           plotOutput("regPlot")),
                  tabPanel("Regression Summary", 
                           verbatimTextOutput("regSummary")))
            )
)
```

server.R:

```
## Coursera Data Science Specialization
#  Class: Delivering Data Products
#
#  Author: Richard Ian Carpenter
#  Date Created: 14 Dec 2015
#  Data Updated: 06 Jan 2016
#
## NOTES: 
#
## I am repeating this course, unrolled from Dec 2015 course due to work obligations.
#
## Beyond the notes and videos for the class and the Shiny website, I used the 
#  following:
#
## This Stack Overflow question from 2013 helped with correcting my R code:
#  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762962/passing-variable-names-to-model-in-shiny-app
#  
## This shiny example to get the regression output to be in the same format
#  that R uses, instead of a table: https://rich.shinyapps.io/regression/
#

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
data("mtcars")

mtcars <- mtcars    

server <- (function(input, output) {

      output$independent <- renderUI({
                            checkboxGroupInput(
                               "independent", "Independent Variables:",
                               names(mtcars)[!names(mtcars) %in% input$dependent],

                               if(input$factor) {
                                   mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
                                   mtcars$vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs)
                                   mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
                                   mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
                                   mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)
                               }

                               )
                            })

      regression <- reactive({
                       lm(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",
                          paste(input$independent,
                                collapse = " + ")),
                          data = mtcars)
                    })

      output$regPlot <- reactive({

            renderPlot({p <- ggplot(regression(), 
                             aes(x = paste(input$independent, collapse = " + "), 
                                 y = input$dependent,
                                 environment = environment())
                             )

                        p <- p + geom_point() #+ geom_smooth()

                        print(p)

            }, height = 700)
        })

      output$regSummary <- renderPrint({
                         if(!is.null(input$independent)){
                                    summary(regression())
                         } else {
                              print("Please select the model's dependent and independent variables.")
                         }
                        })
})
```

Comment: Can you try changing print(p) to just p?

Comment: Same results as 'print(p)': no plot output, but no error message(s), either.

Comment: Try removing the `reactive` around the `renderPlot` (it's already reactive), removing the `environment = environment()` from the ggplot code, and changing `aes` to `aes_string` because you are using strings rather than expressions.

Comment: Exactly right @NicE. I just made those changes too and it works.

Comment: Thank you, @NicE!  That worked, and now I have plot output!  

I had tried 'aes_string' with the 'reactive' part still in the code and kept getting an error about the 'input' not being found.

Comment: Maybe there should be a Shiny-FAQ?

Comment: Uh yeah :) - and better error messages.

Comment: @42: That might be helpful, especially to novice and intermediate R and Shiny users.  I have spent more than a week reading documentation and searching for a means to get the plot output to display.  Most of what I read dealt with specific error messages, those that didn't dealt with the plot visualization itself (coloring, font, icon style, etc.)

Comment: Oh, and just so everyone knows, I'll be including a link to this discussion in my code.

Comment: Maybe NicE could post his comment as a solution and you could accept it so people don't have to go hunting through the comments.